# How to add (crossorigin) attribute on each <img/> tag in react-grid-gallery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add crossorigin attribute on each `img` tag generated by the component `Gallery` from `react-grid-gallery` package.

Tried including `tags` in the images array

```
   const images = [
     {
      src: '/image.png',
      thumbnail: '/image.png',
      tags: [{crossorigin: true}]
     }
   ]
```

Expected output of `Gallery`:

```
<img src='source image' crossorigin ...someAttributes/>
```

Actual Code:

```
import React from "react";
import Gallery from "react-grid-gallery";

const ImageGallery = ({images=[], title}) => {
  if(images.length > 0)
  return (
    <>
    <div style={{overflow: 'auto', height: '400px'}}>
      <span className="lead">{title}</span>
      <Gallery images={images} enableImageSelection = {false}/>
    </div>
    </>
  );
  else{
    return <></>
  }
};

export default ImageGallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tags` option on `Gallery`. Per the [documentation](https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery#image-options):

> **Tags** -
> Optional. An array of objects containing tag attributes (value, title and key if value is element). e.g. `{value: "foo", title: "bar"}` or `{value: <a href={tag.url}>{tag.name}</a>, title: tag.title, key: tag.key}`

Comment: I tried it already. Didn't work for me.